# jssor slider not working properly with css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made three slides with custom css in jssor slider but these three slider are working properly on Firefox but in other browsers these dont work after a lot of research i found the error that i have to use inline css style rather than using a css class for the tags.

Is there any way to get rid from these kind of tags e.g.

```
<h2 style="font-size:white; left:50; top:20; color:#fffff;">Heading  Here</h2>
```

to

```
<h2 class="custom_heading_container">Heading  Here</h2>
```

to make slider compatible with every browsers becuase i have used lot of tags and divs with custom styling

Comment: is your custom CSS for the slider, added in the stylesheet, being overridden by some other CSS for the slider?

Comment: Yes i added all the styles in style sheet and imported into head `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slider_css.css" type="text/css" media="screen">`

Comment: Did you check using the developer tools if the styles are getting overridden?

Comment: Yes i checked every thing i am getting this Chrome Developer Console `Caption 2 definition error, 
Style 'left' not specified. Please always specify caption like 'position: absolute; top: ...px; left: ...px; width: ...px; height: ...px;'.
<p u="caption" t="T" style="transform: perspective(2000px);">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla suscipit nunc urna. Quisque congue venenatis diam. Aliquam dignissim erat ac laoreet lacinia.</p> `

Comment: I working on local host

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move inline styles to css file.

But you'd always specify 'position: absolute; top: ...px; left: ...px; width: ...px; height: ...px;' for caption element.

Comment: its working now but one question about height and width even i dont want to specify the height and width and still causing error in Internet Explorer and Opera is there any way to ignore these height and width cautions from captions becuase somewhere i have used h2 h3 tags also?

Comment: Animation of caption will be calculated base on the size of element. You can disable animation by removing 'u="caption"' from the element, and you don't need to specify size for the element.